# How to get data in array from database with special condition

Tags: php

I have following array example. URL is fetching from database but the data format should be current date and time in stated format.

**example array**

```
$array = array(

array('permalink' => 'http://www.myweb.com/someurl1', 
'updated' => '2012-08-11T04:08:53+01:00'),

array('permalink' => 'http://www.myweb.com/someurl2', 
'updated' => '2012-09-11T04:08:53+01:00'));
```

thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$updated = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your SQL statements with DATE_FORMAT() with mysql.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

If you want to do this from PHP convert your string to a date and then format.
Ex :

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_in_string_format));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php